# kivy buildozer VM

Tags: android, virtual-machine, kivy

I tried to compile kivy with buildozer for android, but it did not work and I could not find the solution for this problem.
So I tried to install the virtual machine from the kivy webside, which is supposed to include this, from this link:

http://kivy.org/#download

But I could not find a .vdi file,and so I wanted to know how I can find this .vdi file and how to install the vm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT: these instructions are outdated, please don't follow them**

The main points:

1. Download the disc image from (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B112pXITp0hJU3dJb25hbWJ3RHM&authuser=0 <- **WARNING** this image is highly out of date and won't work any more) The download is >2GB (6GB after extracted). Extract the file and remember the location of the extracted vdi file.
2. Download the version of VirtualBox for your machine from the VirtualBox download area and install it. (https://www.virtualbox.org/)
3. Start VirtualBox, click on “New” in the left top. Then select “linux” and “Ubuntu 64-bit”.
4. Under “Hard drive”, choose “Use an existing virtual hard drive file”. Search for your vdi file (where you unzipped Buildozer) and select it.
5. Go to the “Settings” for your virtual machine. In the “Display -> Video” section, increase video ram to 32mb or above. Enable 3d acceleration to improve the user experience.
6. Start the Virtual machine and follow the instructions in the readme file on the desktop.

Comment: Just for the newbie like me, the readme file is "inside the virtual machine". it's not in the folder your downloaded. If you don't see it on the desktop on when the virtual machine is launched, it could be hidden behind the popups. In case, you can find it in Folder manager (the folder at the bottom left) in the desktop folder.