# How to build an .aab using Buildozer via Docker?

Tags: python, android, buildozer, android-app-bundle, p4a

I have just seen that [support for AAB files](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/pull/2467) have just been introduced in [Python for Android (p4a)](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android). Considering that, [fom August 2021, new apps are required to publish with the Android App Bundle on Google Play](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle), this is a crucial addition for any Python dev working on Android apps.

Since I'm currently using [Buildozer via Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/kivy/buildozer), I'd like to know which are the steps to make it generating an .aab instead of (or along to) the traditional .apk

For the sake of clarity, here is what I use to run Buildozer from inside a container (using Docker for Windows) to make the .apk file:

```
docker run --interactive --tty --rm --volume "<full_path_to_project_dir>":/home/user/hostcwd kivy/buildozer -v android debug
```

I've seen that there is a temporary [workaround](https://github.com/Android-for-Python/Android-for-Python-Users#how-to-create-a-release-bundle-aab), but it involves using Android Studio, that I don't use and would like to avoid using. Moreover, it refers to virtual machine users, but I'm not sure if this applies to Docker users too.

Comment: I think the workaround about Virtual machines also applies to Docker. And I found this about compiling aab without Android Studio, that looks promising. If someone can adapt it to buildozer's workflow, it would be great: https://www.celersms.com/batch-aab.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The community has finally completed the [AAB support for Buildozer](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/pull/1356). Although it is still a pending pull request, it is already possible to create the AAB, and I have figured out how to do it using Docker.

I have found two very interesting gists that helped me a lot (this one about [creating an AAB with Buildozer on Ubuntu](https://gist.github.com/Guhan-SenSam/35c5ed7da254a7c0141e6a8b6101eb33), and [another one about signing an AAB](https://gist.github.com/Guhan-SenSam/fa4ed215ef3419e7b3154de5cb71f641) on the same platform). However, I have run everything on Windows via Docker, so I think it is a good idea to share how I did it.

1. Clone the [feat/aab-support branch of the Buildozer repository](https://github.com/misl6/buildozer/tree/feat/aab-support) in your local machine:

   ```
   git clone --single-branch --branch feat/aab-support https://github.com/misl6/buildozer.git
   ```
2. Move into the root folder of the project you have just cloned, and build the container:

   ```
   cd buildozer
   docker build -t buildozer-aab .
   ```
3. Before using Buildozer to actually build the AAB, we need to generate a new *buildozer.spec* file, since there are new fields that need to be included for build AAB. To do that, move into the root folder of your app project, remove or rename any old *buildozer.spec* file, and run the following command:

   ```
   docker run --interactive --tty --rm --volume "<full_path_to_app_project_dir>":/home/user/hostcwd kivy/buildozer -v init
   ```
4. Change the following fields in the newly generated *buildozer.spec*:

   ```
   android.archs = arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a
   android.release_artifact = aab
   p4a.branch = develop
   ```
5. Now we need to create a keystore to sign our AAB. To this end, run the following commands on a WSL shell (I used WSL 2 with Ubuntu on Windows 10):

   ```
   mkdir -p /path/to/keystores/
   keytool -genkey -v -keystore /path/to/keystores/<keystore>.keystore -alias <keystore-alias> -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
   keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /path/to/keystores/<your-new-key>.keystore -destkeystore /path/to/keystores/<keystore>.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12
   ```

   The second line will generate a keystore with a validity of 10000 days (which is higher than the [minimum of 25 years required by Google](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key)). You need to replace `<keystore>` with the filename you want to use for your keystore, and set an `<keystore-alias>` (typically the name of your application). You will be asked to add a password. Try to avoid special characters.

   Now move your keystores folder (the one in `/path/to/keystores/`) to a folder that is reachable from outside WSL (e.g. you can move it in your desktop). In the following, I will assume that your keystores folder is now in `C:\Users\test\Desktop\keystores`
6. We are now finally ready to build the AAB. First, be sure to remove any .buildozer folder within your app root folder. Then run the following:

   ```
    docker run --interactive --tty --rm \
        --volume "<app-project-folder>":/home/user/hostcwd \
        --volume "<app-project-folder>\.buildozer":/home/user/.buildozer \
        --volume "C:\Users\test\Desktop\keystores":/home/user/keystores \
        -e P4A_RELEASE_KEYSTORE=/home/user/keystores/<keystore>.keystore \
        -e P4A_RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PASSWD="<your-password>" \
        -e P4A_RELEASE_KEYALIAS_PASSWD="<your-password>" \
        -e P4A_RELEASE_KEYALIAS="<keystore-alias>" \
        buildozer-aab -v android release
   ```

Answer (score -1):

D:\Developing\project\KivyMDFrontEnd>
`docker run --interactive --tty --rm --volume "D:\Developing\project\KivyMDFrontEnd":/home/user/hostcwd --volume "D:\Developing\project\KivyMDFrontEnd\.buildozer":/home/user/.buildozer --volume "D:\Developing\project\KivyMDFrontEnd\keystores":/home/user/keystores -e P4A_RELEASE_KEYSTORE=/home/user/keystores/keystore.keystore -e P4A_RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PASSWD="kivymdfast" -e P4A_RELEASE_KEYALIAS_PASSWD="kivymdfast" -e P4A_RELEASE_KEYALIAS="keystore-alias" buildozer-aab -v android release`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RF4PK.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).