# How to sign AAB file created with Buildozer?

Tags: python, kivy, google-play-console, buildozer, android-app-bundle

I have created a AAB file with Buildozer, but when I uploaded the AAB file on Google Play Console I got an error that says: "The Android App Bundle has not been signed"
What I have to do to sign the AAB file? I am completely lost...

Comment: Is this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69149494/how-to-build-an-aab-using-buildozer-via-docker) helpful ?

Comment: @ApuCoder I will take a look, thanks

Comment: Yes, I solve using the https://github.com/kaedea/aab-signer  - is necessary have jdk installed and added to the PATH to jarsigner work fine - this video show in details   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=56ch3RcuVlU