# buildozer - C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: buildozer

When I run
`buildozer -v android debug`
It ends with this error

```
[INFO]:    -> running configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi --prefix=/home/astrilaa/kivycalc/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/...(and 94 more)           
           working: See `config.log' for more details                                                                                                                  Exception in thread background thread for pid 14805:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.0-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 1633, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.0-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 2557, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.0-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 2261, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.0-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 861, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_77: 

  RAN: /home/astrilaa/kivycalc/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi --prefix=/home/astrilaa/kivycalc/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi --disable-builddir --enable-shared

  STDOUT:
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
checking target system type... arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
checking for gsed... sed
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-strip... arm-linux-androideabi-strip --strip-unneeded
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make -j4 sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make -j4 supports nested variables... yes
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-gcc... /usr/bin/ccache /home/astrilaa/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/astrilaa/kivycalc/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details


  STDERR:

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                     
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 192, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/astrilaa/kivycalc/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1260, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/astrilaa/kivycalc/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/astrilaa/kivycalc/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 709, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/home/astrilaa/kivycalc/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 154, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/astrilaa/kivycalc/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 213, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
  File "/home/astrilaa/kivycalc/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 577, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/home/astrilaa/kivycalc/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/libffi/__init__.py", line 42, in build_arch
    shprint(sh.Command('./configure'),
  File "/home/astrilaa/kivycalc/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.0-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 907, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.0-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 837, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.14.0-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 861, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_77: 

  RAN: /home/astrilaa/kivycalc/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi --prefix=/home/astrilaa/kivycalc/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi --disable-builddir --enable-shared

  STDOUT:
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
checking target system type... arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
checking for gsed... sed
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-strip... arm-linux-androideabi-strip --strip-unneeded
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make -j4 sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make -j4 supports nested variables... yes
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-gcc... /usr/bin/ccache /home/astrilaa/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target armv7a-linux-androideabi21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -mthumb -fPIC
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/astrilaa/kivycalc/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details


  STDERR:

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/astrilaa/kivycalc/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     LC_ALL = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/astrilaa/kivycalc/.buildozer'
#     INVOCATION_ID = 'cab34536ffa845888abc885580633b58'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_VTNR = '7'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/tmp/ssh-gVp07qexptPM/agent.3275'
#     MANDATORY_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/i3.mandatory.path'
#     CLASSPATH = ':/home/astrilaa/.s/java/classes/swt.jar'
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = '4'
#     USER = 'astrilaa'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'i3'
#     DEFAULTS_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/i3.default.path'
#     PWD = '/home/astrilaa/kivycalc'
#     HOME = '/home/astrilaa'
#     LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     JOURNAL_STREAM = '9:21013'
#     aimages = '/home/astrilaa/Anki/ast/collection.media'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '3337'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/i3:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     VTE_VERSION = '5202'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'i3'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     PYTHONSTARTUP = '/home/astrilaa/.pythonrc'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     LOGNAME = 'astrilaa'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-BWRyA4OC8j,guid=838c372083700fa9dddc18065f7f826d'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/home/astrilaa/.Xauthority'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-i3:/etc/xdg'
#     PATH = ('/home/astrilaa/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/astrilaa/bin:/home/astrilaa/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/astrilaa/.s/daetd:/home/astrilaa/.s/daetd/scripts:/home/astrilaa/.s/daetd/bkstree:/home/astrilaa/.s/daetd/rone:usr/local/bin/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130219/sdk/platform-tools:/home/astrilaa/.wine/drive_c/Program '
 'Files/VW/VT/Paul/M16-SAPI5/lib/:/home/astrilaa/android-sdks/tools:/home/astrilaa/android-sdks/platform-tools:/home/astrilaa/android-sdks/tools/bin')
#     PS1 = '[\\u@\\h \\W]$(git_branch)$ '
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/astrilaa/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/astrilaa/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/astrilaa/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I ended in this state after I overcame [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59593341/buildozer-build-failed-couldnt-find-executable-for-cc) problem.

My buildozer wasn't able to download NDK (it wanted r19c), so I downloaded [this](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r19c-linux-x86_64.zip) one. I tried it on Python3.6, Python3.7 and Python3.8
on Ubuntu 18.04 32 bit (i686) architecture.

Comment: There can be a lot of problems causing this error. Maybe it's Python 3.8 fault, Kivy doesn't work good with it. And which OS architecture you have? I made buildozer work only on x64 OS.

Comment: I tried Python3.6 as well and there is the same error. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, 32 bit (i686). I downloaded NDK r19c. Isn't the problem that 32bit system is not supported?

Comment: yes, some part of buildozer doesn't work well on x32 systems. So you should install x64 system and I think it will solve this problem. But don't be surprised if you meet other errors :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34473567/12096447

Try this once. It worked for me in the past.

Comment: @VikramRayavarapu I would like to do it without virtual box. I have seen a video that it works, but I would like to solve the problem on my particular machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is you are running command on a **32-bit operating system**. As mentioned in the [BUG #1007](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/1007)

> Thanks, I saw the logs.. But The Problem was that I was using a 32 bit
> linux system. So the drivers could not work. Then when I tried the
> same thing in a 64 bit linux system. Installed on virtual machine it
> worked fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am having the same problem but i am using a 64 bit linux ubuntu (Windows subsystem)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple and obvious fix(others told me)
you need to

`chmod +x -R ~/Android/android-ndk-r25b`

where your android ndk is